# Write Saved NSString to NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am very new to objective-c xcode macos, but I think this is an easy question.

I am experimenting with writing a saved NSString to an NSTextField. Currently, I have:

```
NSString *teststring = @"10";
```

just to set *teststring to 10 as a test. I am able to programmatically update an NSTextField by using this:

```
[_TextField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]];
```

This works, and updates my NSTextField to read "test." However, what I would like to do is instead of having the NSText write "test," I want it to write the value of *teststring (currently 10).

I assume it is something easy along the lines of (but I know this isn't right):

```
[_ServerVersion setStringValue:[NSString *teststring]];
```

What is the proper way to Write saved NSString to the NSTextField?

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", test]

Comment: That is how you can format a string inside another string, but actually, why not just [_TextField setStringValue:teststring] ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you skaak

```
[_TextField setStringValue:teststring];
```

Was what I needed.

Comment: Nice - you can even do *better* ... how about ```_TextField.stringValue = teststring;``` With Objective-C you can also do *worse* ... how about ```object_setIvar( _TextField, class_getInstanceVariable ( _TextField.class, "_stringValue" ), teststring );``` This may look horrible and may not work everywhere, but you know what, with that in your pocket all those ```readonly``` requirements become mere suggestions lol